# Deployed my react app on Vercel but keep getting blank screen

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, vercel

I was having some issues with deployment then I changed the app's settings on Vercel for node to the version I'm current using and it passed, but when I visit the link it loads for a second then blank screen. I also removed strict mode and nothing. I added homepage to package.json then to "." but still didn't work. Here are the domains:
`moviehub-ten.vercel.app+1 moviehub-git-main-kingmathers92.vercel.app moviehub-auo3bth4l-kingmathers92.vercel.app`
Someone also suggested that changed browsRouter to hashRouter worked for them, I did that and still the same

Here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "movie-hub",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://moviehub-ten.vercel.app",
  "dependencies": {
    "@alan-ai/alan-sdk-web": "^1.8.43",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.12",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.11.12",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.17.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```